# min and max number of hexagons in hexagonal tiling

Tags: geometry, polygons

Is there a way to calculate the maximum and minimum number of hexagons in a hexagonal tiling of a surface with regular identical size hexagons, knowing the area of the surface and the area of the hexagons?

Comment: Min/Max of whole hexagons?

Comment: @Jeffrey L: I mean minimum and maximum number of the hexagons that can be used in the tiling of the given surface knowing the surface area and hexagon area.